# Add a custom element for a related Doctrine Entity in a Zend 2 form

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

I am having trouble with Doctrine Entities in Zend 2 Forms.  I am trying to use a form to add a relationship between two Entities.  I have an Entity as defined below (abbreviated):

```
/**
* 
*
* @ORM\Table(name="resource")
* @ORM\Entity
* @Annotation\Instance("ModuleName\Entity\Resource")
*/
class Resource extends BaseType
{ 
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ResourceRelationship", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="link_resource_resourceRelationship",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="resource_id", referencedColumnName="resource_id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="relationship_id", referencedColumnName="relationship_id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Collection")   
     **/
     protected $relatedResources;
     ... various getter and setters and what not ....
}
```

This creates a One-To-Many relationship between Resource and the ResourceRelationship Entity which holds attributes of the relationship as illustrated below:

```
/**
 * 
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="resourceRelationship")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Annotation\Type("fieldset")
 * @Annotation\Instance("ModuleName\Entity\ResourceRelationship")
 */
class ResourceRelationship
{ 

  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="relationship_id", type="string", length=255,     nullable=false)
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $relationshipId;


  /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Resource", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="resource_id",     referencedColumnName="resource_id")
     * @Annotation\ComposedObject("ModuleName\Entity\Resource")
     * @Annotation\Options({
     *      "target_class":"ModuleName\Entity\Resource",
     * })
     **/
  private $resource;

  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
   * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
   * @Annotation\Options({
   *                "label":"Relationship Type",

   * })
   */
  private $relationshipType;

  ... various getter and setters and what not ....     
}
```

This creates a One-To-One relationship back to a Resource (with additional attributes about the relationship).  These two together allow me to relate my Resource to other Resources and save the "type" of the relationship being saved.  It should also allow Doctrine to cascade the persisting of the objects as necessary (When I save a Resource with a new relationship Doctrine should also create/update the ResourceRelationship).

The problem I am having is in the view code.  I have a widget that searches Resources based on user input, once one is found I need to create dynamically the input that can be placed into the form that will allow Doctrine to process this relationship when the form is processed.  In the end I want my original Resource to have all it's fields intact, and a reference to the ResourceRelationship entity, which should then contain a reference to the other Resource entity.

1) Is this even possible?

2) I would prefer to avoid writing a custom form, and stick with the annotation setup we're using if at all possible.

3) I would prefer to avoid writing custom form processing if at all possible, and instead allow Doctrine to handle figuring out Entity creation

The current view creates a select for the Type of the ResourceRelationship that looks like `<select name="relatedResources[0][relationshipType]" class="form-control">`

The current input for the related Resource entity looks like: `<input name="relatedResources[0][resource]" value="1" type="checkbox">`